# Making property as a reference to class instance in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I want to create a utility class which can have just one instance(singleton) therefore I have made a static method called **getInstance()** which would create a instance and return it to me.

I have posted below the code with a comment where i get and error and the the error description.
Please let me know whats wrong with the code.

Any help appreciated.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.utility.EventManager',{
    extend:'Ext.util.Observable',
    instance: new MyApp.utility.EventManager(), //error as undefined EventManager property  
    statics:{
          // instance: new MyApp.utility.EventManager(),
        getInstance:function(){
            if(!this.self.instance){
                this.self.instance=Ext.create('MyApp.utility.EventManager');
                return this.self.instance;
            }
            else{
                return this.self.instance;
            }
        },

    },

    constructor:function(){
        this.addEvents(
            'success'
        );
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious, that your get an error in `new MyApp.utility.EventManager()` when you are using it in the definition of the class. At the time you `define` the class, it does not yet exist, and therefore you cannot instatiate it with `new`.

The solution is easy, since a singleton class is already a feature of the `Ext` framework. Define your class using the built-in [`singleton`-config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-singleton).

```
Ext.define('MyApp.utility.EventManager',{
    extend:'Ext.util.Observable',
    singleton: true,   
    constructor:function(){
        this.addEvents(
            'success'
        );
    },
});
```

You do not need a `getInstance` method, because the Object `MyApp.utility.EventManager` is always the instatiated singleton.

Comment: Yes Lorenz I knew about singleton feature but the problem is i want to add listener for events in another class for which I would require an instance of my class how would I do that?
What i intended to was something like this.
`var instance=MyApp.utility.EventManager.getInstance();`
`instance.on('success',someFunction());`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but instead of `var instance=MyApp.utility.EventManager.getInstance(); instance.on('success',someFunction());`, you could just write `MyApp.utility.EventManager.on('success',someFunction());`